# WSO2 Identity Server - Tenant Admin Login failure - Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have started facing problem with tenant admin login to the WSO2 Administrative console at random intervals. I am using the WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0.

```
    TID: [46] [] [2016-09-04 19:09:10,344] @tenant1.edu [46] [IS]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.util.AnonymousSessionUtil} -  Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : 46
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : 46
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getUserRealm(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:441)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.AnonymousSessionUtil.getRealmByTenantDomain(AnonymousSessionUtil.java:133)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin.login(AuthenticationAdmin.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : 46
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealmInternal(DefaultRealmService.java:193)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.access$000(DefaultRealmService.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService$1.run(DefaultRealmService.java:153)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService$1.run(DefaultRealmService.java:150)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getUserRealm(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:436)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while reading realm configuration from file
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.buildTenantRealmConfiguration(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:230)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getTenant(JDBCTenantManager.java:323)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getTenant(JDBCTenantManager.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealmInternal(DefaultRealmService.java:172)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Error in building Document
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.replaceSystemVariablesInXml(CarbonUtils.java:1082)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.preProcessRealmConfig(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:241)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.buildTenantRealmConfiguration(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:211)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.replaceSystemVariablesInXml(CarbonUtils.java:1078)
        ... 78 more
TID: [46] [] [2016-09-04 19:09:10,345] @tenant1.edu [46] [IS]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : 46
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-04 19:09:10,895] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-04 19:09:10,896] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext} -  Servlet Exception while including path
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:378)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

During this time I can login to the WSO2 Administrative console using the super admin account. However, all the tenant admin logins are failing. The issue goes away once the identity server is restarted.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other use cases running when you are trying to login like SAML or passive sts requests sent to IS?

Comment: No. this occurs when the tenant admin tries to login to the adminstrative console. And once this happens SAML or Passive STS login also will not happen (for that tenant or for any other configured tenants) till we bounce the wso2 identity server.

Comment: Okay we have encountered this issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5030 and fixed for 5.2.0 version. Can you try out with the latest pack 
https://wso2.org/jenkins/view/All%20Builds/job/product-is_release-productis-5.2.0/org.wso2.is$wso2is/ ?

Comment: we are using a 2 node cluster. Does this occur only in a clustered environment?

Comment: yeah its possible. We reproduced this in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already identified with[1] and fixed for 5.2.0. Can you try with a latest pack and see if you can reproduce this?

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5030

[2] https://wso2.org/jenkins/view/All%20Builds/job/product-is_release-productis-5.2.0/org.wso2.is$wso2is/

Comment: I tried taking out the clustering and ran the identity server in a single node configuration. I am getting the same error. So at least for me it is not a problem that occurs only in clustered environment,

Comment: did you try it with a latest pack? Were you able to reproduce with a latest pack? Please find the latest RC pack at
https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/download/v5.2.0-rc1/wso2is-5.2.0-rc1.zip

Comment: We are running it in prod. Upgrade process has to go though a some processes. when do you expect the GA release for 5.2.0. I will be deploying the the RC in my test server and run a load test.

Comment: GA release will take place as soon as the vote is over (which is expected to close tomorrow). If the vote goes through we will do the GA release immediately in the next couple of days. Let us know how the load test goes?